# How to link Classes/Objects in Angular5?

Tags: angular, class, typescript, angular5

Imagine a flash card learning box with cards and categories. Categories having a title, cards having a content, a linked category (only one) and are linked to another card.

Who should I link them without using services in Angular 5 and Typescript? **By linking I mean, how can the class find out by its own, to whom it is connected?**

```
/* card.ts */
export class Card {
  public id: String;
  public content: String;
  public link: Card;
  public category: Category;

  constructor(
    content, category
  ) {
    this.content = content;
    this.category = category;
    this.generateId();
  }

  private generateId(): void {
    this.id = /* generate unique id */;
  }

  public setLink(card) {
    this.link = card;
  }
}

/* category.ts */
import { Card } from './card';    

export class Category {
  public title: String;
  public slug: String;

  constructor (
    title
  ) {
    this.title = title;
    this.generateSlug();
    this.generateId();
  }

  private generateId(): void {
    this.id = /* generate unique id */;
  }

  public getCards: Card[] {
    /* HERE I DO NEED HELP */
    /* to magic, and find all corresponding cards to that category */
  }
}
```

I've marked inside the code (`HERE I DO NEED HELP`), where a category should know which cards are corresponding to that one category. Later on I'd like just to write `Category.getCards()` to find all cards from that selected category.

Recently I was trying to write service providers to iterate through all cards and find the right ones, but I cannot inject this services to my class to use its advantages.

*PS: I am used to code in PHP and in Laravel you can connect easily classes with n-to-n, 1-to-n or n-to-1 connections.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to decide how your category will get to know the cards. In fact you want to just loop through the cards array and filter out the items that belong to the particular category.

This looks like what will do the job

```
public getCards(): Card[] {
  return cards.filter(card => card.category === this);
}
```

So, the only question is how your category gets to know the `cards` array. Either pass it as a parameter to `getCards()` or to a constructor of a category or in case it is a global variable just import it. This is up to you to decide how you go on.

Comment: Considering that the amount of categories and cards are changing constanstly, the problem sounds now like a storage problem: Where to store the newly added cards and categories? I was hoping, Angular could do that for me, but I think I will have to switch to a database-like solution.

Comment: You'll need an API to store data, and communicate using REST. Laraven has direct access to database because it executes on the server, Angular executes in a browser.

Comment: And there is no ORM-Angular-Local-Storage-Shizzle out there?

Comment: local storage is limited with size (around 5MB in average and could be even less), you can use [indexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) which has no size limitation but has [less browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=indexeddb) instead; however both can be cleared any day by clearing the cache so I would not call it anyhow stable. This is a client side programming, you can actually forget most that you had in PHP